# A slider to control volume of mp3 music in livecode

Tags: livecode

I was wondering is there was a way to control the volume of something with a
slider so that if the slider was one the value 0 there would be no sound, and
if it was on 100, the sounds was as high as it could go

For the script, I tried something like "set the playLoudness of player 1 to
value" Which obviously didn't work, and so yeah, I'm asking for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here.

```
on scrollbarDrag theValue
   set the playLoudness of player 1 to theValue
end scrollbarDrag
```

Of course you need set the startValue of the slider to 0, and the endValue to 100.

Comment: thank you so much Scott  , so I write this in the script of the scrollbar ?  , will this work with livecode version  7.1.4 ? that is the version my school uses

Comment: Yes to both.  scrollbarDrag is the default message sent to a scrollbar/slider, just like a button receives mouseDown, mouseUp, etc.